# Escaping XML using Java and Marklogic

Tags: java, xml, marklogic

I am loading XML into a Marklogic database using Java and Marklogic's XCC API.  Before I do so, I use Apache Commons to escape the elements' contents (StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml).  Upon loading the contents, though, I error out due to a curly brace character in the contents.  escapeXml doesn't handle the curly brace.  My questions are:

1) Is that a Marklogic specific issue (maybe with XCC) or is it an issue with XML in general?
2) Are there other characters that could also cause a problem (i.e. not escaped by the escapeXml routine)?
3) Is there a different routine that could be used to avoid this and any future undesired characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not escape contents when using XCC, it escapes them itself so you would be doing double-escapes.  However curly brackes are generally not something XML complains about, perhaps you are using the Invoke instead of Insert methods.
( i.e. then XCC would try to interpret your content as XQuery )

Could you provide a sample of your content and code snippet ?

Comment: Thanks for the input DALDEI.  Thanks to your answer, I was able to figure it out.  Our routine uses a templated call where the content is inserted into the template.  So content gets placed in a call looking like: "collectionbatcat:update-record-list(\"<%BATCH-ID%>\", <%RECORD-LIST%>)";  The curly brace is being treated as part of the xquery command - causing the error.